# Can I use my Jawbone ICON to listen to Netflix on my iPhone4?

Tags: iphone

Question says it all. Is there some config to do this? Phone is not jailbroken.

Comment: I got a Jawbone ERA and it does the job, still not sure whether this is possible with the ICON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just got an ICON last weekend and it plays all audio output I've thrown at it (phone calls, podcasts, games). Netflix itself, I couldn't test since we don't have that here in Europe, but I don't see why it should be any different than the other apps.
What is important, though, is that A2DP support is installed on the ICON. In my case, it was out of the box, but apparently that's different with older ones. In that case, you apparently need to go to http://mytalk.jawbone.com and install a software update for your headset.

Comment: This is correct, I have since updated the firmware with mytalk and it works fine. Thanks!